# How to install the PyQt5?

Tags: python, module, pyqt5

I have been searching to resolve this problem for two days. I tried a lot of ways, searched the answer on google, but didn't find a single solution to the problem. I want to know why `PyQt5` is not working even if it is installed.

Although the `pip show` option is working, and the `pip install` option is already satisfied but it is still causing the issue and the code is not executing.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(1000, 200, 300, 300)
    win.setWindowTitle("ibilalkayy")

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
window()
```

**`pip show PyQt5` result**

```
Name: PyQt5
Version: 5.15.2
Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit
Home-page: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Author: Riverbank Computing Limited
Author-email: info@riverbankcomputing.com
License: GPL v3
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: PyQt5-sip
Required-by: PyQtWebEngine
```

**`pip install PyQt5==5.15.2`**

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5==5.15.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from PyQt5==5.15.2) (12.8.1)
```

**Code execution and error**

```
python3 /Path/to/tutorial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Path/to/tutorial.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Comment: Note: Do not delete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65632672 and publish a new post with the same content as this is an abuse of the system, and the ability to create post could be blocked

Comment: try installing: `sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5`. Is there a file called PyQt5.py in the same folder as your script?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases that can happen:

1. When you're doing this on a new IDE
2. When you're running this file in a new app,(Example, you're running this on PyCharm, etc.)

This generally happens when your IDE or the output app is new and you've not set python in path. So, if you have python already installed, try running the file in CMD or adding python to path.

Comment: I am using sublime text.

Comment: I tried to run the code in the command line interface but it is still giving me an error that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'`. However, if I activate the `venv` and try to import the `PyQt5` it works, but I don't know to make this `venv` working when writing code in text editor

Comment: text editors generally don't come with autocompletes and you generally have to install them, So, if it works in venv then I think you should try to reinstall and add it to path.
Also, try installing miniconda and add it to path. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your path
`python3 /Path/to/tutorial.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Path/to/tutorial.py", line 1, in <module> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'`
To
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Ok stay happy

Comment: The path is `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. I just hide the path. Not happy with this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a  PyQt5 with pip3 command.

```
sudo pip3 install PyQt5==5.15.2
```

Comment: The result is already satisfied but still not working.

Comment: Might be possible u have multiple version of python3 pls check with which version  file is running and in which version the library was installed.

Comment: I have python 2.7.18 and python 3.9.1 installed

Comment: instead of python3 could you please try to run with python3 /Path/to/tutorial.py

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what everyone else has mentioned, there's one more scenario which I suspect might be the case. Make sure you haven't given any of the folders or directories included in the path of your file ('tutorial.py') the same name as the module (i.e. 'PyQt5').

*That's all I have to add. I agree this "answer" would be better suited as a comment but I don't have enough reputation so this is the only way I could bring up this point...*